# how to disable the tabs using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have three subtabs under main tab, when I click main tab defauly I am displyaing tab1 data using jquery grid, now initially I need disable the tab2 and tab3. how?

Comment: You should include a sample of your code with the question to make it easier (possible, even) for people to help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the jQuery UI tabs [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#method-disable).  Note that it's zero-based so this disables the 2nd and 3rd tabs.

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs( { disabled: [1, 2] } );
```

Comment: On double click on any row in jquery grid can i enbale tab1?

something like this

   ondblClickRow: function(rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
                    $("#tabs").tabs({ enabled: 1 });
                    var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs();
                     var selected = $tabs.tabs('select', 1);

but its not working?

thanks

Comment: Sorry I got it

i did something like this on doubleclick evnt.. 

$("#tabs").tabs('enable',1);
thanks for yoru time

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you are using the jQuery UI tabs:

You can use `"disable"` to disable a given tab after initialization:

```
jQuery("#myTab").tabs( "disable" , index )
```

Alternatively, if you need to disable tabs when the tabs are first displayed, you can pass the `disabled` option and an array of tabs to disable:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs( { disabled: [1, 2] } );
```