# Disable and enable jquery tabs based on user selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, tabs

I am using jquery tabs to present some data , I want to give user an option to choose if she/he wants it to be displayed as tabs or in one after another. When the user selects from a drop down how she/he wants to view I remove/add the ui-tabs classes but this approach doesnot seem to work. There is also one workaround to destroy and create it on every call but I suppose this is not a good approach. Can any one suggest me what to do ...

Comment: I think you might want a look [here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629939/how-to-disable-the-tabs-using-jqueryhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629939/how-to-disable-the-tabs-using-jquery

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks ....but the link does seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$('#tabsDiv').tabs('disable', 1); //where 1 is the tab number
```

or apply a class on specific tab

```
.ui-tabs-disabled {
    display: none; 
}
```

Refer [this](http://www.remotesynthesis.com/post.cfm/adding-and-removing-tabs-with-jquery-and-jquery-ui) link for more info

Comment: but this will hide my content as well....i want content of the tabs to come one after another just the same as if there were not tabs.

Comment: Then you have to do somethings other than only dealing with tabs.like when tabs hiding getting those content and appending to another tab something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "destroy" );
```

Comment: yes...m using this method only presently but was looking for a better method