# Disable a tab using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tab structure like this:

```
 <ul class="g-tabs-tabs" style="width: 160px;">
      <li class="g-tabs-tab" data-idx="0">General</li>
      <li class="g-tabs-tab" data-idx="1">Extension</li>
      <li class="g-tabs-tab" data-idx="2">Lines</li>
 </ul>
```

I am not using JqueryUI. So i don't want to do [this as answered for same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629939/how-to-disable-the-tabs-using-jquery)

On hovering over a tab it changes the color(see fiddle).
If a tab is disabled it should not change the color.

How do i disable third tab?

[See Fiddle For Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Arvind_955/Lej2P/)

Comment: You mean [(this)](http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Lej2P/1/) ??

Comment: Yes exactly this is what i want.

Comment: But how i can add this `disabled` using jquery? I am not good with it. Should i replace this?

Comment: Added as an answer. Just add the class using jQuery: `.addClass("active")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to add a class which makes it look disabled by muting the color and overriding the existing `:hover` classes. Also, need to disable the mouse events to make truly disabled.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Lej2P/1/***

*Relevant CSS: (just add this class)*

```
.g-tabs-tabs > .disabled, .g-tabs-tabs > .disabled:hover {
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: `<li class="g-tabs-tab disabled" data-idx="2">Lines</li>`   Can u use jquery to add `disabled` ?

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you disable it by adding some class (let's say `g-tabs-disabled`). So just add the following rule in your css :

```
.g-tabs-disabled:hover {
    background-color:#f4f4f4;   
}
```

or if you have support for `:not` in CSS, you can merge it with the other rule :

```
.g-tabs-tab:not(.g-tabs-disabled):hover {
    background-color:#0000FF;
}
```

See fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Lej2P/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="g-tabs-tabs" style="width: 160px;">
    <li class="g-tabs-tab" data-idx="0">General</li>
    <li class="g-tabs-tab" data-idx="1">Extension</li>
    <li class="g-tabs-tab" data-idx="2" data-type="disabled">Lines</li>
</ul>
```

Insert CSS

```
li[data-type=disabled]:hover{background-color:#FFFFFF;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable hover effect you can do sth like this

```
 $('ul li:nth-child(3)').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'transparent');
  });
```