# Multiple Form Validation in Asp.net MVC using Jquery.valid()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

Here is my scenario i have 3 accordion layout. Each accordion contain 1 form. Like that

```
<div id="collapseOne">

@using(Html.BeginForm("","",FormMethod.Post,new{id="formOne"}))
{

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Name)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.City)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.City)

    <input type="button" value="Next" id="btnOne" />

}

</div>
<div id="collapseTwo">


@using(Html.BeginForm("","",FormMethod.Post,new{id="formTwo"}))
{

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Age)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Age)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Address)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Address)

    <input type="button" value="Next" id="btnTwo" />

}

</div>
<div id="collapseThree">

@using(Html.BeginForm("MyAction","MyController",FormMethod.Post,new{id="formThree"}))
{

     @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Email)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Email)

     @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.City)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Email)

    <input type="submit" value="Finish" id="btnThree" />

}

</div>
```

Now validation checks doing well when i press Next Next in above accordions.
But when someone comes directly to 3rd accordion and try to press finish then it validate only 3rd form. 
Here is my jquery

```
function PageEvents(){
  $("#btnThree").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if($("#formOne").valid()==false){
      // Open first Accordion
    }
    else if($("#formTwo").valid()==false){
      //Open second Accodion
    }
    else{
      if($("#formThree").valid()){
         $("#formThree").submit();
      }
    }
  });

$("#btnOne").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($("#formOne").valid()) {
        //trigger accordion two
        $("collapseTwo").trigger("click");
    }
});
$("#btnTwo").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($("#formTwo").valid()) {
        //trigger accordion two
        $("collapseThree").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

If you want more description i will provide.
Please guide me how to validate those forms which are not opened yet and user come directly in 3rd accordion and press finish button...

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to do a multi-step wizard?

Comment: what's jquery code on btnOne and btnTwo?

Comment: Exactly @StephenMuecke but actually it is not wizard but act like wizard.

Comment: @teovankot i updated my Question please take a look

Comment: @azhar_SE_nextbridge. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097) shows an alernative using a single form and validating each section on the fly. I'm not sure how you could make this work. Your posting your back to the same method so if you post the 1st form - it would fail server side validation (e.g. if say the email was required)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with validatin hidden fields, jquery validation by default don't validate hidden fields, you can just change default:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: []
});
```

Buy also you can diasble tabs, that shouldn't be allowed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2629972/1849444) is example how to do it.

But the best way is to use miltistep Wizard like [this](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Multi-Step-Form-Wizard-Plugin.html).

Comment: but in this case when i click on btnThree then it returns all form valid even they are not valid yet..

Comment: when whole div is hide then obviously it return true against validation.

Comment: now i get your problem, updated the answer with solution

Comment: and if some controls are decision based like if dropdown value is yes selected then show Age textbox.. Till then it should be hide by default.By your solution it goes to validate all fields.

Comment: yes, you right. then maby it's easier to disable tabs that user can't use by your logic?

Comment: Or use @Stephen approach.

Comment: Yes it may be option to disable tabs. Is it good for user experience.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66658/discussion-between-teo-van-kot-and-azhar-se-nextbridge).

Comment: for user experience best will be use multi-step wizard as @Stephen say... Tabs really for another situation. I provide one of then in answer

Comment: I am on chat can you please come there?